# Existence of Quotients in Locally Ringed Spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, schemes, quotient-spaces, ringed-spaces

This is part of an exercise (2.14) in Qing Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry. I'm going to be verbose to see if there's something fundamental I'm missing. Actual questions will be numbered.

Let $G$ act on a ringed topological space $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, ie we have a group morphism $\phi\colon G \to \operatorname{Aut}_{LRS}(X)$.

The full exercise wants to finally show that the  *quotient space* exists in the category of ringed topological spaces. It is the object defined by the property of being a ringed topological space $(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ together with a *quotient morphism* $p \colon X \to Y$ that is universal among all maps that satisfy $p \circ \sigma = p$ for all $\sigma \in G$ ($G$-invariance) and that any morphism $f \colon X \to Z$ that is also $G$-invariant factors through $p$ uniquely by $f = \tilde{f} \circ p $ for some $\tilde{f} \colon Y \to Z$.

1. First I had trouble even with the unwinding of definitions of how the group acts on a locally ringed space.
   I assume that this means that we can identify the group action on the (topological) set as $(\phi(\sigma), \phi(\sigma)^\#): (X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to (X, \mathcal{O}_X)$. With abuse of notation the topological morphism as $\sigma \colon x \mapsto x\sigma := \phi(\sigma)(x)$ and the map of sheafs is $\sigma^\# \colon \mathcal{O}_X \to \sigma_* \mathcal{O}_X$ or explicitly $\sigma ^\# \colon \mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_X(\sigma^{-1}(U))$. Is this correct?
2. I also assume that the $G$-invariance $p \circ \sigma = p$ can be translated into $p(x \sigma) = p(x)$ as topological spaces and $(p \circ \sigma)^\# = (p_* \sigma^\#) \circ p^\#$ as maps of sheafs so that $\mathcal{O}_X(p^{-1}(U)) = \mathcal{O}_X(\sigma^{-1}(p^{-1}(U)))$. Is this correct?

The quotient is then constructed by $Y = X/G$ as quotient set, and $p \colon X \to Y$ the projection. The topology is given by the quotient topology giving $V \subset Y$ is open if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. I've shown that $p$ is an open morphism of topologies.

3. Part of the exercise wants one to show how $G$ acts on the ringed space $p^{-1}(V)$ (do they mean $(W, \mathcal{O}_{W})$ for $W = p^{-1}(V)$?) explicitly and that, in particular, $G$ acts on the ring $\mathcal{O}_X(p^{-1}(V))$. This feels very elementary but I can't really see how the group morphism $\phi$ gives a group morphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}_{LRS}(p^{-1}(V))$ and let alone the action on the ring.

---

Corrected question 2. with comment from @Mindlack.

Comment: 1. is correct. The notation of 2, is misleading: it’s not $p_* \circ \sigma^{\sharp} \circ p^{\sharp}$ but $(p_*\sigma^{\sharp}) \circ p^{\sharp}$, since $p_*$ is a functor, not a map. You should also double-check your sets and inverse images: if $p^{-1}(U)$ exists, then $U \subset Z$ and thus $\sigma^{-1}(U)$ is undefined.

Comment: @Mindlack Ah, that's true. So the map of sheafs should be $(p_* \sigma^\#) \circ p^\# \colon \mathcal{O}_Y \to p_* (\sigma_* \mathcal{O}_X)$ and give us the identification $\mathcal{O}_X(p^{-1}(U)) = \mathcal{O}_X(\sigma^{-1}(p^{-1}(U)))$.

But since $(-)_*$ is a functor shouldn't we have $p_* (\sigma_* \mathcal{O}_X) = (p \circ \sigma)_* \mathcal{O}_X = p_* \mathcal{O}_X$ by the $G$-invariance of $p$?

Comment: For 3, $p^{-1}(V)$ is an open subspace of $X$, stable under $G$ (for point-set topology). So the action of $G$ on $X$ restricts to an action on $p^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: @Mindlack For $x \in p^{-1}(V)$ we have $p(x) \in V$ and by $G$-invariance $p(x\sigma) \in V$ so it is stable under $G$. 

But what about the ring action? $\operatorname{Aut}(p^{-1}(V))$ seems to be the isomorphisms $p_* \mathcal{O}_X \to p_* \mathcal{O}_X$ which are sheafs on the topological space $Y$ a $G$ action is a morphism $\sigma^\# \colon p_* \mathcal{O}_X \to \sigma_* (p_* \mathcal{O}_X)$ but this doesn't work for the reason you said earlier that $\sigma$ acts on $X$ not $Y$. What is the action on the ring like? What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: Later on in the exercise they want to define a sheaf on $Y$ by $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)$ as the $G$-invariant elements of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(p^{-1}(V))^G$.

Comment: No: $p^{-1}(V)$ is a subspace of $X$ – so $G$ acts naturally by restriction. If $W \subset p^{-1}(V)$ is open, $\sigma \in G$, we have a natural $\sigma^{\sharp}: \mathcal{O}_X(W) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(\sigma^{-1}(W))$.